# MySQL regexp for matching list of numbers in a string

Tags: mysql, regex

I have several rows with strings similar to this: `1,19|11|14,2`
The info I want to look at is: `19|11|14` (which is a list of the numbers, 19 11 and 14)
This info should be matched to see if any of the numbers are in the range between  8 and 13

What's the most effective way to accomplish this? I tried using a regexp like:
 `[^0-9]*(8|9|10|11|12|13)[^0-9]*`
But this would also match the number 9 which is actually 19.

Other methods for parsing the string is also welcomed, only functions available in MySQL 5.0 can be used.

Comment: Your Regex currently states 0 or more non-numerical characters followed by a number between 8 and 13 followed by 0 or more non-numerical characters. It's not clear what you are attempting to match?!

Comment: @Cags For example I would like to match the number 8 in `1,8|17,1` and not in `1,18|17,1`. I would only like to match 8 if the preceding isn't a number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I remember MySQLs Regex support is very simplistic I'm not sure how possible this will actually be. I don't believe it supports word boundaries or look around assertions. How about this...

```
(^|[^0-9])(8|9|10|11|12|13)([^0-9]|$)
```

Comment: Finally, your proposed solution solved my issue. I'd tried others like ^[[:digit:]]{10}$ and '^[0-9]{10}$'. Only with yours I get the expected value :)